# Is it possible to get the size of an image using Bytes.IO?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where two imported librairies are not working well with each other, I know it is possible to get the size of an image using :

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(logo)
width, height = img.size
```

But I'd like to know if it is also possible to do that usin `io` ? I couldn't find anything on that

```
logo = request.FILES.get('logo')
img = io.BytesIO(logo.read())
... ?
```

Comment: The  short answer is no. Or not directly. BytesIO represents just an array of bytes. The image is represented as a shapeless string of bytes, with metadata indicating the actual shape of the image once is transformed back to numpy, PIL or something else. However, that metadata is also encoded within the byte string, so not directly accessible.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I see, I'll try to use something else instaed of using PIL

Comment: You could make PIL to read the `io.BytesIO` (I believe is something like `Image.fromBuffer(....)`) and then get the width and height as it was a PIL image. But not directly from `io`.